# Why this approach to differentiate $\log_{10}(x+1)^x$ does not work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I am trying to differentiate $\log_{10}(x+1)^x$ but I don't get the correct answer, could you please help me?

I know that one correct solution is the following:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\log_{10}(x+1)^x &= \frac{d}{dx}e^{x\ln(\log_{10}(x+1))}\\ 
&= e^{x\ln(\log_{10}(x+1))}(\ln(\log_{10}(x+1))+\frac{x}{(x+1)\log_{10}(x+1)\ln(10)})\\ 
&= \log_{10}(x+1)^x(\ln(\log_{10}(x+1))+\frac{x}{(x+1)\log_{10}(x+1)\ln(10)})
\end{align}
However, I also tried this other approach but I don't know why it doesn't work:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\log_{10}(x+1)^x = (\log_{10}(1+x)^x)(\ln(\log_{10}(1+x)))(\frac{1}{(x+1)\ln(10)}),$$ using these rules:
$$\frac{d}{dx}a^x = \ln(a)a^x$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\log_a(x) = \frac{1}{x\ln(a)}.$$

Could you explain me why it doesn't work? What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I should use notation $\left[\log_{10}\left(x+1\right)\right]^{x}$. This to avoid confusion with $\log_{10}\left[\left(x+1\right)^{x}\right]$. I was a victim of that confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First part removed; the question arose from confusion between $\log_{10} \left[ ( x + 1 )^x \right]$ and $\left[ \log_{10} (x+1) \right]^x$

---

Your second try using $a^x$ does not work.  The formula only applies when $a$ itself is not a function of $x$.

Comment: What is wrong in the second line? Thanks.

Comment: @DOMiguel Well, this is embarrassing.  I was sure you had added in something extra but now it looks like your math checks out.  Are you sure the question is $( \log_{10} ( x+1 ) )^x$ and not $\log_{10} ( (x+1)^x ) = x \log_{10} ( x + 1 )$ as mentioned by a now-deleted answer?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, $(log_{10}(x+1))^x$.